# Inheritance in variables, access from parent to child variable value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a super class to access DataModels in a SQLite database (in Android). I want to change a variable value in the child but use it in the parent.

This is the portion of code from the superclass:

```
public class DataModel<T> {
    public static String table = null;

    static String getTableName(){
        String tableName = null;
        Class<?> enclosingClass = DataModel.class;
        tableName = enclosingClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "s";
        if(table != null){
            tableName = DataModel.table;
        }
        return tableName;
    }
}
```

The child class:

```
public class User extends DataModel {
    static {
        String table = "test_users_table";
    }
}
```

I have some issues with the table variable: It comes null. Adding more strange behaviour the process enters the if statement even of being null the var.

I supose I am doing it bad and I am missunderstanding some concept. What is the right aproach?

Beside this, how can I get child class name? I always take datamodels as a result to `enclosingClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "s"`.

**EDIT:** The class DataModel will be the base class for all my database models. What I try is to make a class with the ability to encapsulate SQL queries, I mean, when I need to load a concrete model like a user, I call the static method `User.find(id)`, which connects to the SQLite and returns an instantiated User object with the data loaded. I could do this directly on the USer class, but I try to do this in the DataModel in order to do `Product.find(x)`, `Post.find(x)`. Later I could add methods like save to encapsulate INSERTS and UPDATES.

At last I would have a base class which would do all the job for me, and the db methods would be written once.

In this concrete code portion I am trying to pass to the DataModel the table name for this example (users).

Comment: Leave out `String` which introduces simply a local variable. But in general one should really not do something like that. Another child class will change the same static.

Comment: I also tested `static { table = "test_users_table"; }` with the same result.

Comment: It may be the "issue" stems from defining a second `String` named `table` in `User` - you could instead try `DataModel.table = "test_users_table"`. However, I think it would be a better idea to explain what it is you ultimately want to achieve, as I am sure there will be a better/more OOP approach you can take.

Comment: Perfect, I will EDIT my post.

Comment: Static fields and methods are not Overrided nor Overloaded.

Comment: Just remove the static from everywhere, you don't need then

Comment: Have a read about abstract classes instea

Comment: Abstrct has the same behaviour.